# SymPy: How can I check, if symbol is a constant or a variable?

Tags: python, constants, sympy, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

In sympy, I want to create a constant e.g. to represent the speed of light.
Thus I initialize `c` with the keyword `constant=True`.

Later I want to check, if a symbol is a constant or a variable.
Unexpectedly the command `c.is_constant()` outputs False.

```
c = Symbol( 'c' , constant=True, real=True )
c.is_real       # outputs True as expected.
c.is_constant() # outputs False. This is unexpected !
```

How can I check, if a symbol is a constant or a variable ?

Comment: SymPy already has a constant for the speed of light but it's also fine to use an ordinary symbol. Why do you want to distinguish between a constant and a variable? What difference would it make? There is almost certainly a better way of solving your actual problem.

Comment: Looking at the code/docs of `is_constant` I see that it does not check the `assumptions`.  So setting that assumption as you do does not make a difference.  From the docs it looks like `is_constant` makes more sense when applied to an expression than to a single symbol.  Assumptions keywords are not constrained.  `foobar=True` is allowed, but only means something if I add some sort of test.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin : I want to use the linearity of a function: `f( const*x ) = const*f( x )`, but I don't want to put something outside the brackets, if I face the product of two variables (NOT: `f(yx)=y*f(x))`. Thus I want to check, if `x`,`y` or `const` are constants or variables.

Comment: @hpaulj : Thanks for the hint that the is_constant property seems to be taylored for composite expressions! That makes sense to me!  But I don't understand the SymPy's assumptions system, yet. Could you give me an example of how to give a symbol a custom boolean property like foobar and how to check for it using the assumption system you mentioned?

Comment: I don't think that declaring a symbol to be a "constant" is a good way of doing whatever it is you are trying to do. I think you can get a better answer if you ask a question about your actual problem i.e. you want to do some sort of manipulation based on knowing that your function `f` commutes with multiplication by some symbols but not others.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a Symbol, creating a `Quantity` object should do the job.
The code example below does what you are trying to do.

```
from sympy.physics.units.quantities import Quantity

c = Quantity('c')
print(c.is_constant())
```

Output:

```
True
```

In case you need something else, or more customized, you may try doing something similar to what Sympy does for constant values such as e and pi, you can find the source code for that here:

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/46e00feeef5204d896a2fbec65390bd4145c3902/sympy/core/numbers.py#L3421-L3578

And for more information on why the `is_constant` method was returning `False`, check out this

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.is_constant

Comment: Thank you, Luis, this is a possibility to distinguish: variables = Symbols, constants = Quantities, **BUT there is a drawback of using Quantities** to me: It seems that equations containing Quantities are displayed uglily by IPython.core.display in Spyder's IPython console. A nice latex display of equations is important to me. Thus this is not a satisfactory option to me.

Comment: In such case, you could try the other thing I mention, which is emulating what SymPy does for defining PI and E. Which is creating a class for your constant, like they do here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/46e00feeef5204d896a2fbec65390bd4145c3902/sympy/core/numbers.py#L3421-L3578

Answer (score 0):

Look what happens when I construct a symbol with various keywords:

```
In [93]: c = Symbol( 'c' , constant=True, real=True, foobar=True )
In [94]: c._assumptions
Out[94]: 
{'constant': True,
 'real': True,
 'extended_real': True,
 'hermitian': True,
 'commutative': True,
 'imaginary': False,
 'finite': True,
 'complex': True,
 'infinite': False,
 'foobar': True}
```

Those keywords, plus some defaults, are put in a `dict`.  I included your `constant`, and random choice of my own `foobar`.  Neither has special meaning.

The `is_constant` method does not look for this assumption value:

```
def is_constant(self, *wrt, **flags):
    if not wrt:
        return False
    return not self in wrt
```

We have to study its docs to see what a `wrt` is.

Specifying an `assumption` is one thing, actually using it is quite another.